# Is there a .net library that has a persistent immutable Vector class (as found in Clojure/Scala)?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, clojure, functional-programming

I've spent a good hour googling, and can find various .NET immutable Lists, Sets and Maps. I have not been able to find a persistent immutable Vector though.

Something like Scala's immutable Vector is what I'm after (and I believe its similar in Clojure). It must be callable from a C# library.

Does such a thing exist in Microsoft-land?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out [ClojureCLR implementation](https://github.com/clojure/clojure-clr/tree/master/Clojure/Clojure/Lib).
It is an implementation of Clojure language on top of CLR/DLR execution engine.
I guess you can't simply copy&paste the code to your project but with little work you can extract specific persistent data structures.
Look inside Clojure\Clojure\Lib for implementation such as PersistentVector.cs

Ido.

Answer (score 1):

There's a .NET implementation ([callable](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Collections/PersistentVectorC.html) from a C# library) of persistent vectors in the [FSharpX.Collections](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Collections) package, also [available](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharpx.Collections) on NuGet.

Here's the usage example from the project's front page:

```
// Create an empty PersistentVector and add some elements
PersistentVector<string> vector =
    PersistentVector<string>.Empty()
        .Conj("hello")
        .Conj("world")
        .Conj("!");

PersistentVector<string> vector2 = vector.Conj("!!!").Update(0,"hi");

Console.WriteLine(vector2[0]); // hi
Console.WriteLine(vector[0]);  // hello
Console.WriteLine(vector2[3]); // !!!

Console.WriteLine(vector.Length);  // 3
Console.WriteLine(vector2.Length); // 4

// remove the last element from a PersistentVector
PersistentVector<string> vector3 = vector2.Initial;

Console.WriteLine(vector3.Length); // 3
```